# collectionView reloadData inside parse block

Tags: ios, objective-c

when the code run it doesn't call  collectionView reloadData

photoArray is NSMutableArray and initialized in viewDidLoad

```
photoArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and parse query

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            [SVProgressHUD show];

            PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"photo"];
            [thumbnail getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSData *imageData = data;
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                    [photosArray addObject:image];
                    [self.collectionView reloadData];

                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }

                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

            }];

        }

    }
```

Note the same code was working in another project , so how to solve it

Comment: First of all, don't call `reloadData` in a loop.  Add all your objects first.  Second, make sure you're on the main thread.

Comment: `reloadData()` is supposed to be called on the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's not working is probably because you're reloading from a background thread.  Wrap the call to `reloadData` as follows:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
});
```

As an aside, don't do this inside the loop which adds objects to your datasource (`photosArray`).  Move that dispatch below the loop.

Comment: But in parse the completion blocks are executed on the main thread

Comment: I (obviously) did not know that.

Comment: What about moving below the loop?